# Should I have separate pages for different categories or one page with multiple unrelated categories for SEO?

Tags: seo, page, categories

If my website caters to multiple categories which are mutually exclusive to each other, then which of the following is more preferable in terms of SEO?

- having one page with important keywords from all categories
- having individual page for each category with their specific keywords

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! Search is not about keywords. It is about whole language. Create content for users and not machines. If you do that, then all will work out as it should. Now, I want to ask a question. ***Are you worried about the performance of category and tag pages?*** Cheers!!